# Add Additional input auth before Registration of user in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a registration form for the user what i want is **after the user submits the form** open a modal and display an input field say `code` and check if the user inputs a valid `code` the register the user in.

currently i have `code` field in my registration for and i can check if its valid on the form submit but i want to do it in a modal in another step.
How do i open a modal on submit and then proceed with the registration once the user enters the code?

**Form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

    @if ($errors->has('name'))
        <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                            </span>
    @endif
</div>

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="email" class="control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

    @if ($errors->has('email'))
        <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                            </span>
    @endif
</div>

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

    @if ($errors->has('password'))
        <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                            </span>
    @endif
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password-confirm" class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="logonForgot">
        <label for="promo-code" class="control-label">Promo Code*</label>
        <input id="promo-code" type="text" class="form-control" name="promo_code" required>
    </div>
    <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Register
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many way to do this.

You can do it with pure js.

```
<from action="yoururl">
   your form here
   <button onclick="myActionWhenClick()">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
  function MyActionWhenClick(){
     Open Modal Fucntion here...
  }
</script>
```

Or if your are using jQuery you can do this:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitForm"> Submit</button>
<script>
   $("#submitForm").submit(function (){
        $("#modalWhitCode").modal("show") //example if you are using bootstrap
    }
</script>
```

And then you can use ajax to validate or whatever you use now to check the code, use onclick to validate function and then use :

js pure

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

or jquery

```
$( "#myForm" ).submit();
```

Comment: that's not how it works in laravel, i think. see the updated code in question.